# How to achieve portal scene inside another portal scene in ARCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

How to place a portal scene inside another portal scene? I have no found such kind of example or documentation on ARCore site for android.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as 123. Put walls surrounding inner portal inside outer portal. The trick is as following: these walls must be invisible outside and must be visible inside. For that you need to make these walls single-sided. Doors of an outer portal and of an inner portal have to be single-sided as well and rotated 180 degrees about Y-axis (their normals must be pointing in the opposite direction).

> **Look at this useful SO post**: [How to create a Portal effect in ARKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910190/how-to-create-a-portal-effect-in-arkit-just-using-the-scenekit-editor).

[image]